# Pointer to a member function in an inaccessible base

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, pointer-to-member, private-inheritance

The compilation of the next example :

```
class A
{
  public:
    void foo()
    {
    }
};

class B : private A
{
  public:
    using A::foo;
};

int main()
{
    typedef void (B::*mf)();
    mf func = &B::foo;

    B b;
    (b.*func)();
}
```

fails with next errors :

```
main.cpp||In function ‘int main()’:  
main.cpp|18|error: ‘A’ is an inaccessible base of ‘B’  
main.cpp|18|error:    in pointer to member function conversion
```

I understand that the A is not accessible base of B, but I am using the `using` keyword. Shouldn't it allow the access to the function foo?

What are relevant paragraphs in the standard that prevents the above to be compiled?

Comment: Good question. Because one can do `b.foo()`, but not `&B::foo`.

Comment: Exact duplicate - [Function member pointer with private base](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942949/function-member-pointer-with-private-base). Not voting to close because the other question doesn't have an accepted answer, but [@Michael Burr's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942949/function-member-pointer-with-private-base/6946317#6946317) seems like it should have been.

Comment: @eran, where have you been? I actually had to dig the spec and quote the exact same sentence again to convert the infidels! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access to *members* of `A` is governed by chapter 11 "Member Access Control", but pointer-to-member conversions are covered by 4.11. In particular, 4.11/2 states that you can't convert a `T A::*` to an `T B::*` when you can't convert an `B*` to a `A*`.

Here's a slight variation of the question:

```
class A
{
  public:
    void foo()
    {
    }
};

class B : private A
{
  public:
    using A::foo;
};

int main()
{
    typedef void (A::*amf)();
    typedef void (B::*bmf)();
    amf func = &A::foo;
    bmf f2 = static_cast<bmf>(func);
}
```

We're still talking about the same function. It's not the name lookup of `B::foo` that fails (`using` takes care of that), it's the fact that the type of `B::foo` is `void A::*()` which cannot be converted to `void B::*()`.

Comment: To make it even clearer: `void (A::*amf)() = 0; void (B::*bmf)() = amf;` fails on the second statement.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. In my answer I said that B::foo is used for overload resolution, and overload resolution only. For any other purpose its A::foo, and you claim that because its A::foo the assignment fails. Now, I would understand if you'd say that your answer completes my. But how is it 100% opposite, if its exactly the same?

Comment: @litteadv: you claim, literally "you can do b.foo, but **not** &B::foo." I show that you **can**. See also http://ideone.com/LGphq.

Comment: Regardless, I believe the user asked why using `using` doesn't solve the problem, you seem to not being able to address that.

Answer (score 6):

Since `foo` in `B` is inherited from `A`, `&B::foo` is identical to `&A::foo`, and has type `void (A::*)()`. When you write

```
typedef void (B::*mf)();
mf func = &B::foo;
```

you are trying to convert from `void (A::*)()` to `void (B::*)()`. Since `B` inherits privately from`A` you cannot do that.

Comment: You could add that the following is correct: `typedef void (A::*mf)(); mf func = &B::foo;`, to insist on the fact that the issue regards pointer-to-member-function conversion and not accessibility.

Comment: @LucTouraille "_that the issue regards pointer-to-member-function conversion and not accessibility_" what do you mean?

Answer (score -1):

I have simplified the problem. The main problem is given below:

```
int main() 
{ 
    &B::foo; 
}
```

Here I am trying to access the address of foo which is defined in class A and inherited privately. Therefore it is giving compilation error.

Using only imports the function. It does not change the access specifier of foo.